# Entity Framework 6 change datacolumn name at runtime

Tags: entity-framework

I'm working on a existing SQL database. I created a complex type "Address" for one of my entities and I use the attribute "ColumnAttribute" to define the mapping in my table.

It works fine.

Now, I want to reuse my complex type "Address" for a another table.

But, for existing reasons, the names of column are differents.

How do I change the column names for this specific table without the use of inheritance ? Or having to create two classes of type Address for that.

```
public sealed class class1 
{
    public Adresse Adresse{get;set;}
}

public sealed class class2 
{
    // Need to change all ColumnAttributes for this specific class
    public Adresse Adresse{get;set;}
}

public sealed class Adresse : IAdresse
{
    #region IAdresse Membres

    [Column( "ADRESSE" )]
    public string Adresse1 { get; set; }

    [Column( "CODE_POSTAL" )]
    public string CodePostal { get; set; }

    [Column( "VILLE" )]
    public string Ville { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have a suitable test ready.
Assuming Complex Type is working correctly as you say.

> I created a complex type "Address" .... It works fine.

Try Fluent API you might be able to override.

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext {
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
     // attempt override standard name of complex property
     modelBuilder.Entity<Class2>().Property(t=>t.Adresse.Adresse1).HasColumnName("BetterName");

 }
}
```